# Can I convert a step down transformer to step up?

Tags: transformer, inverter

I have a center tapped stepped down transformer 12-0-12 240 V.

I need to convert it to a step up transformer 12 V to 240 V and I need it to be centre tapped.

I am making an inverter circuit to convert 12 V DC to 220 V AC.

The current rating is 3 A.

Comment: Do you have a question? You might want to consider the difference between RMS and peak voltage to help you frame the question.

Comment: Where do you need the center tapping?

Comment: Yes, you can ... Use the transformer the "right" way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run most transformers *backwards*. But realize that you won't get much current at 240 VAC. The current rating is for the 12-0-12 side.

This is a 24 V * 3 A = 72 VA transformer. Your output current at 240 VAC will be at most 72 VA / 240 V = ~300 mA.